# is this function one to one

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a really simple question here.

Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x-3)$ one to one?

This is across all real numbers of course.

I only ask because Mathematica says it's not but I think it's because Mathematica also considered the complex cases as well.

But across all real numbers, I do believe $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x-3)$ is one-to-one. I can't see why it would not be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\frac12 \ln (x-3)$ is an increasing function, it must be injective; however, this requires $x>3$, otherwise $x-3$ is negative.

Comment: As I thought. Thank you. Edit: Yes I realize that.